# Using innerHTML to change div value based on checkbox

Tags: javascript, forms, innerhtml

I'm trying to change the text in a div based on whether or not a checkbox has been checked. I'm new to Javascript, so this is what I've attempted... if anyone can point me to where I've gone off the rails, I'd appreciate it.

```js
function SetContent() {
  if (document.complianceformAA.compliance_AA.checked == true) {
    document.getElementById('ComplianceSummary').innerHTML = "A compliance concern is found for Key Element I-A.";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('ComplianceSummary').innerHTML = "Key Element I-A is met.";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="Concerns">
  <form id="complianceformAA">
    <input type="checkbox" id="compliance_AA">
    <label for="compliance_AA">Compliance Concern?</label>
  </form>
</div>
<button onclick="SetContent ();">Generate Summary</button>
<div id="ComplianceSummary"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use [named elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables), instead select by the `id` using [`Document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

```js
function SetContent() {
  if (document.getElementById('compliance_AA').checked) {
    document.getElementById('ComplianceSummary').innerHTML = "A compliance concern is found for Key Element I-A.";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('ComplianceSummary').innerHTML = "Key Element I-A is met.";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="Concerns">
  <form id="complianceformAA">
    <input type="checkbox" id="compliance_AA">
    <label for="compliance_AA">Compliance Concern?</label>
  </form>
</div>
<button onclick="SetContent ();">Generate Summary</button>
<div id="ComplianceSummary"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, indent your code:

```
function setContent() {
  if (document.complianceformAA.compliance_AA.checked == true) {
    document.getElementById('ComplianceSummary').innerHTML="A compliance concern is found for Key Element I-A.";
  } else {
   document.getElementById('ComplianceSummary').innerHTML="Key Element I-A is met.";
  }
}
```

Second, you don't get elements like that.
You get it through one of this methods:

1. [`getElementById('id')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

This gets the element based on ID. For example, this:

```
document.getElementById('checkbox');
```

Would get this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"></input>
```

2. [`getElementsByTagName();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)

This gets all elements with the same tag.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button');
```

could return

```
HTMLCollection [ <button>, <button>, <button>, <button> ]
```

with this HTML code:

```
<div id="buttons">
  <button>
  <button>
  <button>
  <button>
</div>
```

3. [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

This returns all elements with a certain class name. For example:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('a')
```

could return

```
HTMLCollection [ <button.a>, <button.a>, <button.a>, <button.a> ]
```

With this code

```
<div id="buttons">
  <button class="a">
  <button class="a">
  <button class="a">
  <button class="a">
</div>
```

4. [`getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)

This gets all elements with the name specified. For example:

```
document.getElementsByName('hi');
```

could return

```
NodeList [ <button.className> <button.className> ]
```

with this HTML code:

```
<div id="buttons">
<button name="hi" class="className">
<button name="hi" class="className">
</div>
```

So what you want for your javascript is this:

```
function setContent() {
  checkBox = document.getElementById('compliance_AA');
  if (checkBox.checked) {
    document.getElementById('ComplianceSummary').innerHTML = "A compliance concern is found for Key Element I-A.";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('ComplianceSummary').innerHTML = "Key Element I-A is met.";
  }
}
```

Here's an example:

```js
    function setContent() {
      checkBox = document.getElementById('compliance_AA');
      if (checkBox.checked) {
        document.getElementById('ComplianceSummary').innerHTML = "A compliance concern is found for Key Element I-A.";
      } else {
        document.getElementById('ComplianceSummary').innerHTML = "Key Element I-A is met.";
      }
    }
```

```html
<div id="Concerns">
  <form id="complianceformAA">
    <input type="checkbox" id="compliance_AA">
    <label for="compliance_AA">Compliance Concern?</label>
  </form>
</div>
<button onclick="setContent();">Generate Summary</button>
<div id="ComplianceSummary"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function SetContent(){
   var chk = document.getElementById("compliance_AA");
   var summary = document.getElementById("ComplianceSummary");

   if(chk.checked){
    summary.innerHTML="A compliance concern is found for Key Element I-A."
   }else{
    summary.innerHTML="Key Element I-A is met."
   }
}
```